# Extract the rows with decreasing values of column of an ordered dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time, categories

I have a data frame that has information about buildings, their status and the time when the status is recorded.

For the sake of simplicity I encoded them into numbers in this example table:

| id | time | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 1 |
| 101 | 2 | 2 |
| 101 | 3 | 3 |
| 102 | 1 | 2 |
| 102 | 2 | 1 |
| 102 | 3 | 2 |
| 102 | 4 | 3 |

I want to extract the IDs where their status is not strictly increasing. By that I mean that their status should always increase as time increases just like ID 101

As you can see ID 102 at time 1 has status 2, but at time 2 it has the status 1.

So if you feed this table to the function it should return a list of ID where it only contains 102.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get differencies per `id` in one `groupby` in lambda function (for avoid double groupby) for check, if all values are greater like `0` and for list filter indices with inverted mask for values NOT matched condition:

```
#if necessary sorting per id and time
df = df.sort_values(['id','time'])

s = df.groupby('id')['status'].apply(lambda x: np.all(np.diff(x) > 0))

L = s.index[~s].tolist()
print (L)
[102]
```

If need rows use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for possible filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
#if necessary sorting per id and time
df = df.sort_values(['id','time'])

df1 = df[~df.groupby('id')['status'].transform(lambda x: np.all(np.diff(x) > 0))]
print (df1)
    id  time  status
3  102     1       2
4  102     2       1
5  102     3       2
6  102     4       3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach: `set_index` to "id", then `groupby` it, find differences in consecutive "status" entries and see if any value is less than 0; this creates a boolean Series where any negative value is True. Then groupby "id" again and see if any "id" has negative value; this also creates a boolean Series. Filter the index of the Series with its values.

```
msk = df.set_index('id').groupby(level=0)['status'].diff().le(0).groupby(level=0).any()
out = msk[msk].index.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[102]
```

Comment: Thank you! works like a charm! but I had to use the numpy version due to my large dataset.